# get value of the dropdown same as label

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Dropdown to get the options from json file. I'm getting the options but the value of the dropdown is shown as below.my question how to get the value is same as label ie.,  value="4.90a-ea02" label="4.90a-ea02"

`<select name="version" class="form-control" ng-model="myObj.Version" 
                  ng-options="item as item.version for item in contver| unique:'version'|orderBy: '-version'" >`

[image]

Comment: `item.version as item.version for item in......`

Comment: thanx @Satpal, it's working

Comment: an FYI: as your labels are the same as text content, you're doubling up where you don't need to ... you can safely remove the label attribute if you want - label defaults to text content if not specified

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="version" class="form-control" ng-model="myObj.Version" 
                  ng-options="item.version as item.version for item in contver| unique:'version'|orderBy: '-version'" >
```

Comment: Please add a short description to your answer, what this code does and how it fixes the initial problem. Don't just post an uncommented block of code.

Answer (score 0):

just change the `ng-options="item as item.version for` to  `ng-options="item.version as item.version for`

```
<select name="version" class="form-control" ng-model="myObj.Version" 
                  ng-options="item.version as item.version for item in contver| unique:'version'|orderBy: '-version'" >
```